# Create a Django fixture file that leaves some fields unchanged when loaded into DB

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to create a fixture that is written to the DB using `loaddata`, and overwrites some fields of an existing record, but not all of them?

For example, suppose I have a table in my DB called `app_foo`:

| id | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "a" | "b" |
| 2 | "c" | "d" |

The corresponding YAML fixture file for this would look like:

```yaml
- model: app.foo
  pk: 1
  fields:
    bar: "a"
    baz: "b"
- model: app.foo
  pk: 2
  fields:
    bar: "c"
    baz: "d"
```

How would I modify this fixture such that:

1. Records 1 and 2 have an empty `baz` field when loading the fixture into a fresh empty database.
2. When the fixture is loaded into a database already containing records 1 and 2 that have values for `baz`, they aren't overwritten with `NULL`.

I thought that I could do something like this:

```yaml
- model: app.foo
  pk: 1
  fields:
    bar: "a"
- model: app.foo
  pk: 2
  fields:
    bar: "c"
```

or this:

```yaml
- model: app.foo
  pk: 1
  fields:
    bar: "a"
    baz:
- model: app.foo
  pk: 2
  fields:
    bar: "c"
    baz:
```

But both attempts overwrote the `baz` field for DB records 1 and 2 with `NULL`. This isn't specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) for fixtures, but is an empty field in a fixture implicitly `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) you linked

> Each time you run loaddata, the data will be read from the fixture and
> re-loaded into the database. Note this means that if you change one of
> the rows created by a fixture and then run loaddata again, **you’ll wipe**
> **out any changes you’ve made.**

Django does not set values for fields that are not in fixture but they default to [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default) field value, which is `NULL` in case you set [`null=true`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: Thanks for this information! So to recap, it's not possible to construct a fixture that selectively overwrites some fields of a DB record it contains?

Comment: No, you can create for instance data migration or your own management command for following purpose